# no module named cairo - python and pip

Tags: python, pip, python-2.x, pycairo

I am trying to build `openuds` and I get the error `no module name cairo`, I surfed a bit and found installing `pycairo` will solve it. 1) How do I fix this install error?

```
python manage.py createcachetable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/hari/openuds/testuds-master/Python-2.7.14/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/hari/openuds/testuds-master/Python-2.7.14/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/hari/openuds/testuds-master/Python-2.7.14/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/hari/openuds/testuds-master/Python-2.7.14/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/hari/openuds/testuds-master/server/src/uds/__init__.py", line 78, in ready
    from . import REST  # To make sure REST initializes all what it needs
  File "/home/hari/openuds/testuds-master/server/src/uds/REST/__init__.py", line 210, in <module>
    Dispatcher.initialize()
  File "/home/hari/openuds/testuds-master/server/src/uds/REST/__init__.py", line 206, in initialize
    __import__(__name__ + '.' + package + '.' + name, globals(), locals(), [], -1)
  File "/home/hari/openuds/testuds-master/server/src/uds/REST/methods/reports.py", line 38, in <module>
    from uds import reports
  File "/home/hari/openuds/testuds-master/server/src/uds/reports/__init__.py", line 80, in <module>
    __init__()
  File "/home/hari/openuds/testuds-master/server/src/uds/reports/__init__.py", line 76, in __init__
    __import__(name, globals(), locals(), [])
  File "/home/hari/openuds/testuds-master/server/src/uds/reports/stats/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .login import StatsReportLogin, StatsReportLoginCSV
  File "/home/hari/openuds/testuds-master/server/src/uds/reports/stats/login.py", line 45, in <module>
    import cairo
ImportError: No module named cairo
```

so I tried to **install pycairo** and I get the following error, Could someone help me, please

```
python -m pip install pycairo 
Collecting pycairo
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a6/54/23d6cf3e8d8f1eb30e0e58f171b6f62b2ea75c024935492373639a1a08e4/pycairo-1.18.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pycairo
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pycairo ... error
  Complete output from command /home/hari/openuds/testuds-master/Python-2.7.14/env/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-_hOJAx/pycairo/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-sp61DQ --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cairo
  copying cairo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cairo
  copying cairo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cairo
  copying cairo/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cairo
  running build_ext
  Package cairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'cairo' found
  Command '['pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'cairo >= 1.13.1']' returned non-zero exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pycairo
  Running setup.py clean for pycairo
Failed to build pycairo
Installing collected packages: pycairo
  Running setup.py install for pycairo ... error
    Complete output from command /home/hari/openuds/testuds-master/Python-2.7.14/env/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-_hOJAx/pycairo/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-SBY9Xo/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/hari/openuds/testuds-master/Python-2.7.14/env/include/site/python2.7/pycairo:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cairo
    copying cairo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cairo
    copying cairo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cairo
    copying cairo/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cairo
    running build_ext
    Package cairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'cairo' found
    Command '['pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'cairo >= 1.13.1']' returned non-zero exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/hari/openuds/testuds-master/Python-2.7.14/env/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-_hOJAx/pycairo/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-SBY9Xo/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/hari/openuds/testuds-master/Python-2.7.14/env/include/site/python2.7/pycairo" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-_hOJAx/pycairo/
```

2) Also in Java we have maven which will install the dependencies by its own like this any other tool is available for building python packages?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pycairo is a Python bindings for the [cairo graphics library](https://cairographics.org/). Pycairo [doesn't provide](https://pypi.org/project/pycairo/1.18.0/#files) precompiled binary wheels so `pip` has to compile it from sources. And to compile Pycairo you need cairo installed. So start with

```
apt install libcairo2
```

Or install the binding form your distribution:

```
apt install python-cairo
```

Comment: Also see more detailed solution at https://github.com/pygobject/pycairo/issues/89

Comment: needed `libcairo2-dev` for it to work for me

Answer (score 0):

If you recently updated python versions, you could link the missing .so files.

E.g.

```bash
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cairo/_cairo.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cairo/_cairo.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

If other libraries are complaining about being missing, then look at the relevant modules, e.g. cairo in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cairo/`

Answer (score 0):

Use `pycario`. Install it using the below command.

```
pip install pycairo
```

Usage:

```
import cairo

with cairo.SVGSurface("example.svg", 200, 200) as surface:
    context = cairo.Context(surface)
    x, y, x1, y1 = 0.1, 0.5, 0.4, 0.9
    x2, y2, x3, y3 = 0.6, 0.1, 0.9, 0.5
    context.scale(200, 200)
    context.set_line_width(0.04)
    context.move_to(x, y)
    context.curve_to(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)
    context.stroke()
    context.set_source_rgba(1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.6)
    context.set_line_width(0.02)
    context.move_to(x, y)
    context.line_to(x1, y1)
    context.move_to(x2, y2)
    context.line_to(x3, y3)
    context.stroke()
```

Output image:

[image]